# auto return type in main

Tags: c++, c++14

This may be a trivial question, however I don't know (was unable to find) its answer. Consider the following C++14 code:

```
auto main() 
{
    return 0;
}
```

In my opinion, this code should be perfectly valid. The return type should be typed-deduced as `int` in the declaration `auto main()`. However, both g++ (4.9.2) and clang++ (600.0.54) complain about it, spitting out

```
error: 'main' must return 'int' (g++)
```

or

```
error: cannot initialize return object of type 'auto' with an rvalue
  of type 'int' (clang++)
```

Any reasons why this happens? From a consistency point of view, the code above should compile successfully, imho.

Comment: Thanks, for some reason didn't bumped into this question. However, even adding `return 0` doesn't do the trick.

Comment: Well, no. Read the comments & linked defect report. You must declare the return type, you cannot have it deduced.

Comment: Ok, will read it carefully, thanks again for the link.